# Element type is invalid: expected a string when using TouchableHighlight

Tags: react-native

I am having problems when adding the `TouchableHighlight` component from react-native, and I am given the following error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string

Everything works fine if I delete this

The code is the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Image, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Card, CardItem, Right, Left, TouchableHighlight} from 'native-base';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'

import HeaderMenu from '../Header/Header';

class homeScreen extends React.Component {

    state = {
        noticias: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('URL')
        .then(res => this.setState({
            noticias: res.data
        }));
    }

    render() {
        const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <HeaderMenu title='Noticias'/>
          <ScrollView>
                <View style={{borderTopColor: 'white', borderTopWidth: 2}}>
                    {
                        this.state.noticias.map((noticia, index) => (
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigate('SingleScreen')}>
                                <CardItem key={index} style={{height: 100, padding: 5, borderBottomColor: '#dee0e2', borderBottomWidth: 1}} >
                                    <View>
                                        <Image style={{width: 120, height: 80, alignSelf: 'stretch'}} source={{uri: noticia.imagen}} />
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={{height: 80, flex: 1, paddingLeft: 10}}>
                                        <Text style={{fontSize: 12, marginBottom: 8}} >{noticia.titulo}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <Icon style={{marginTop: 40 ,width: 20, height: '100%', color: '#343537', justifyContent: 'center', paddingLeft: 5}} name="chevron-right" />
                                </CardItem>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        ))
                    } 
                </View> 
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

export default homeScreen;
```

Already checked other answers but none of them solve my problem.

Comment: Can you add your full stack trace? Also, when you destructure navigate is it a function? i.e.  const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

Comment: Can you comment out `HeaderMenu` to verify that it's not the problem?

Comment: You are importing TouchableHighlight from native-base, I guess you want to import it from react-native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. You are doing this.

```
import {Card, CardItem, Right, Left, TouchableHighlight} from 'native-base';
```

You are importing `TouchableHighlight` from `native-base` which is wrong. You have to remove it.

You have to import `TouchableHighlight` from react-native

```
import {View, Text, Image, ScrollView,TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. In this case, the array will always be with data but should check if before as you suggested.

Comment: @JetLagFox I have updated my answer. Have you checked it out?

Comment: Finally. Thank you!